# How to remove Fragment from TabsAdapter, ViewPager and SherlockFragmentActivity

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-viewpager

I'm using ActionBarSherlock, have some tabs connected with SherlockFragments and user can change these tabs (select only some of them to show in settings).

How can I remove all fragments and add only selected ones?

```
public static class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements
        ActionBar.TabListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is just a matter of correctly implementing `getCount()` and calling `notifyDataSetchanged()` when the user changes the selected tabs.